# Using the switch statement instead of if

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

so I just started programming and I started with c#. In the book I'm reading (learning c# 3.0), one of the exercises was this.

> Exercise 5-2. Create a program that prompts a user for input, accepts an integer, then
>   evaluates whether that input is zero, odd or even, a multiple of 10, or too large (more
>   than 100) by using multiple levels of if statements.

I managed to to this but the next exercise was

> Exercise 5-3. Rewrite the program from Exercise 5-2 to do the same
>   work with a switch statement.

I understand how switch statements work, but, I'm not sure how to work out if the user input number is odd/even, multiple of 10 and so on, and not use an if statement. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried???

Comment: A switch with a boolean thing swithced on, and a case true and case false.

Comment: Here's a link to [that page in the book](http://books.google.com/books?id=CgLgh5vQcPgC&pg=PA120).

Comment: I can understand your problem. It seems like a bad exercise. It doesn't seem to be suited for a `switch` statement. Of course @BenjaminGruenbaum is right any `if (b) { ... } else { ... }` can be rewritten into `switch (b) { case true: ...; break; default: ...; break; }` but that is not a realistic use. You _could_ take "odd or even" and "multiple of 10" together, assuming you made sure the number was not negative, by switching on `num % 10`, but I don't think that is a realistic use either.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen exactly.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help, I don't think I would have worked that one out by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int input = ...
switch (input)
{
    case 0:
        Console.WriteLine("Zero");
        default;
    default:
        switch (input < 100)
        {
            case true:
                switch (Math.Abs(input) % 10)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine("Multiple of 10");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                    case 4:
                    case 6:
                    case 8:
                        Console.WriteLine("Even");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Odd");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Too large");
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

I don't think you can do this with a single `switch` in C#—unless you make it so massive as to account from every number from 0-100. You might be able to do it with a single [`Select` statement in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx), which is similar to a C# `switch` but has significantly different semantics.

Comment: That should be never used in production code, but nice job :)

Comment: What about input==0 ? Also try to respect the order in which the conditions were given

Comment: @TGO Thanks, I'd forgotten about the zero case. Although I don't think you can handle the conditions exactly in the order they were given. You have to check < 100 before you check whether it is divisible by 10 or 2.

Comment: @p.s.w.g whatever, as Jeppe Stig Nielsen commented in the question, the exercise itself is ill formed

Comment: @TGO Agreed. This is not at all the kind of code I'd write in any real-world situation. There are much more relevant cases where a switch can be legitimately applied.

Comment: In the exercise text, maybe it was implicit that `input` is not negative. But of course if your `input` is `-2`, the above code may claim that's `"Odd"`. In reality, no sane programmer would switch on a `bool` expression, and also a `switch` with only one `case` label and (possibly also) one `default` label would be written as an `if` in practice.